# How to get sequence dependency from dictionary (yaml file) with specific key using Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, dependencies, config

I have a YAML file (such as config file), which looks like:

```
Network:
  name: Network
  require: ~
IPaddress1:
  name: IPapp
  require: Network
IPaddress2:
  name: IPweb
  require: Network
Server1:
  name: AppServer
  require: IPaddress1
Server2:
  name: WebServer
  require: IPaddress2
```

And I parsed it using PyYAML library:

```
def get_config(configpath):
    with open(configpath, 'r') as file_descriptor:
        data = yaml.load(file_descriptor)
    return data
```

I got a dictionary.
Now how can I create list of dependencies using key "require" to both directions for specific value (Network,IPaddress ... etc)?
I mean:
Down direction for Server2:

```
[Server2, IPaddress2, Network]
```

Down direction for Server1:

```
[Server1, IPaddress1, Network]
```

But with Up direction is more complicated. For Network as example:

```
[Server1, IPaddress1, Server2, IPaddress2, Network]
```

Because Network has 2 dependecies (IPaddress1 and IPaddress2).
Finally, What I'm trying to do: if I want create Server1, I must create Network, then IPaddress2. If I want delete Network, I must delete Server1-2 and their IPs

Comment: This has nothing to do with YAML apart from that you just happen to load the strings that form the keys and values for your Python dicts from there. You can easily describe the problem you are encountering with just Python.

Comment: As you see above yaml file is an example. It might be anything type. Main question is how to get "dependencies" with key "require" in right order.